# How to implement delay time (microsec order) on system call in C

Tags: c, linux-kernel, delay, embedded-linux, system-calls

How can I implement a delay time on system call in C?
I'm using a stm32f429 and hc-sr04 sensor. I need to give a trigger pulse of 10 microseconds. I tried with:

```
gpio_set_value(TRIG, 1 );
for(k=0;k<16;k++)
asm("nop");
gpio_set_value(TRIG, 0 );
```

but I think that asm("nop") is inaccurate for delay.
What is the best way in terms of accuracy to implement a delay of order of microsecond into a system call?
Another small question: about asm("nop"), knowing that the ARM processor of my device has frequency 180MHz, how can I calculate the corresponding delay time of single asm("nop")?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you really running linux on that? To do accurate delay with a NOP you will have to disable interrupts and other task switching, and even then are at the mercy of the bus arbiter.  Consider using one of the many hardware timers.

Comment: You can do it in the driver. 
call 

spin_lock_irq(&lock);
udelay(10);
spin_unlock_irq(&lock).

Comment: Hi Chris!
Yes, I already disabled interrupts. However for curiosity, how can I calculate how much asm("nop") corresponds in terms of time?
Hi John! Between spin_lock and spin_unlock I must put only delay or entire my code into system call?
Thank you for your answers

Comment: only delay (udelay) and remember it is a delay loop  ... and what do you mean by system call ?

Comment: Hi John. I see system calls as interface to the kernel. They provide the interface to services provided by OS itself.
However thank you for your answer.

Comment: Then do not add this in a system call. You might lockup the entire system.

Answer (score 2):

For short delays, use the kernel functions:

```
udelay(unsigned long usecs) - microsec delay
mdelay(unsigned long msecs) - millisec delay
```

These are timed loops implemented in an arch independent manner and are much better than below approach:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        ;
```

which is CPU speed dependent.

Note: Putting a very large value (15000 mili sec) then its possible the kernel will give a soft-lockup. This is a hardcoded value when the signal must give a soft-lockup. Also using `udelay() or mdelay()` is not interruptible during the wait, therefore as alternatively, you may want to consider using kernel timers.

Comment: Hi askb!
So, you think that in my case, since I'm working at kernel level, using udelay is the better choice in terms of accuracy?
Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Anth as mentioned you may want to use `udelay()` or kernel timers (if you want use interruptible wait).